# Angular translate default language with Static Files Loader

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello I am developing app on angular and I use angular translate plugin with static file loader. Everything works fine but I have question is there a way to set a defaul language? I know that you can set a fallbackLanguage but it doesn't work for me or maybe it doesn't work with static file loader? I mean that in my app language is loaded via user setting in system (by sysytem here I mean our database holds what user culture type is) so there can be a user that has some strange locale set and app doesn't have translations for it than I would like to show it in English by default, same thing would come when there is missing translation for users language. Here is way I set up whole translateProvider:

```
    $translateProvider.useStaticFilesLoader({
        prefix: '/languages/',
        suffix: '.json'
    });

    $translateProvider.fallbackLanguage('en_US');

    $translateProvider.preferredLanguage('pl_PL');
```

And way I think of it is: if I don't have pl_PL.json file en_US.json should be loaded but instead in template the key isn't translated but just printed. Maybe I need to do dometing more?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$translateProvider.preferredLanguage('en_US');
```

You don't know that the user wants *pl_PL* during app initialisation; you have to wait until you've checked your database and then call `$translate.uses('pl_PL');` to override the preferred language.